# Is there a proper way to write a build stage for LibGDX project .yaml

Tags: continuous-integration, libgdx

I am configuring my project's CI/CD and I was curios if there is a way to properly write a .yaml script for a build stage

Answer (score 0):

This is the .yml script that I have written for the build stage of my libgdx prject's ci-cd pipeline

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 week
```